# How to rename array keys to a string value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-key

I have an array that conatins a list of objects, then am mapping through the object to display a list of data.
Right now when user add item to the list , I want to change the index of that newly added Item to a string value.

What am getting is this

```
 [{…}]
0: {categories: 'A very nice shawarma for 2!', discount: 0, id: 7,}
```

Instead what I want is the index key 0 of the array to change to a string value rather than the automatic 0, 2,3... inedex key base

Something like ...

```
"String" : {categories: 'A very nice shawarma for 2!', discount: 0, id: 7,}
```

Comment: You can't able to do that. You have to make the parent array to object to giving string key. Because Array in js is used only with numeric, auto-incremented keys, but javascript objects can hold named key-value pairs.

Comment: why would you use array if you dont want the number index, just use an object?